# Hide other field on field change - Suite Script 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I would like to hide the ID 'custrecord_hrx_vendor_status_list'
once item has selected in select box ( options ).

Here is my code.
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ClientScript
*/

define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/error'],

```
function (error) {

    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
        var fieldId = context.fieldId;
        if( fieldId === 'custrecord_hrx_negotiation_type' ){
            var selectedType = currentRecord.getText(fieldId);
            console.log(currentRecord.getField('custrecord_hrx_vendor_status_list'));

            currentRecord.updateDisplayType({
                id: 'custrecord_hrx_vendor_status_list',
                displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged
    }


}
```

);

----HERE IS THE ERROR

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message says, you are trying to load a module that is not available. You are writing a client script, and trying to load a module that is only for server-side scripts.

Additionally, `N/currentRecord#CurrentRecord` does not have a `updateDisplayType()` method.

The way to hide a field in a SS2.0 client script is:

```
currentRecord.getField({
  fieldId: 'custrecord_hrx_vendor_status_list'
}).isDisplay = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

N/ui/serverwidget Module doen not work in client script.you must use like this to hide `currentRecord.getField( { fieldId: id } ).isDisplay = false;`